# Apply random Pacing in Jmeter Without Timers

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have 10 samplers which i have to apply a pacing of 120 to 180 Seconds . I know that i can use Throughput Timers to Implement this but i wanted to know how to implement it without using timers . I guess we can use Beanshell scripting for this . But iam not quite sure on how to implement. Thankyou .

Answer (score 0):

1. You won't be able to implement pacing without Timers because you need to add a delay and [the relevant test element for introducing a delay is a timer.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)
2. If you want to introduce pacing using scripting be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so the obvious choice would be [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer)

Example code:

```
//Sets the pacing to be between 120 and 180 seconds
Long Pacing = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(120000, 180000)

//If the response time is less than the pacing ms, set the delay value to myDelay
if ( pacing > 0 )
{
    //iPacing is equal to the int value of pacing if pacing is not equal to null, otherwise iPacing is null
    Integer iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null;
    log.info(String.valueOf(iPacing));
    vars.put("myDelay", String.valueOf(iPacing));
    return iPacing;
}
//The response time is greater than or equal to 4500 ms, set myDelay to 0
else
{
    vars.put("myDelay", "0");
    return 0;
}
```